# Is it possible to call a static member function override from the base class?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to call the static member function override `B::baz()` from the base class member function `A::foo()`?

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual void foo() { bar(); baz(); }
  virtual void bar() { std::cout << "A::bar()" << std::endl; };
  static void baz() { std::cout << "A::baz()" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  void bar() override { std::cout << "B::bar()" << std::endl; };
  static void baz() { std::cout << "B::baz()" << std::endl; }
};
```

The output of

```
B b;
b.foo();
```

is

```
> B::bar()
> A::baz()
```

so `A::baz()` is called in `A::foo()`.

Comment: why do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: No, a static method to be able to call a function without an object (an instance). So, in fact, `A::bar` and `B::bar` are two different function, and compiler knows which is called in compiled time.

Comment: [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is one common way to solve this.

Comment: @NeilButterworth The base class calls a framework function that takes a function pointer. For each derived class, the function pointer needs to point to a different function.

Comment: @DrPepperJo Well, the 'overriding `static` method' might be an overkill in such a case. Why not let each subclass register itself, choosing how it wants to do that? (`static` method of chosen name, lambda, free function)?

Comment: You might be letting yourself be misled by convenient shorthand. The convenient `virtual void foo() { bar(); baz(); }` is shorthand for `virtual void foo() { this->bar(); A::baz(); }`. When viewed this way, does it still look like overriding `baz()` is plausible?